# Call setter dynamically from Javascript constructor

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I want to configure object via constructor, like that:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.options = {};
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
      const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, key);
      if (desc && desc.set) {
        // can't reach that condition
        this[key] = val;
      } else {
        // all properties sets via that condition
        this.options[key] = val;
      }
    });
  }
  set bar(val) {
    this.options.bar = val.toString();
  }
  set baz(val) {
    this.options.baz = parseInt(val, 10);
  }
}

const f = new Foo({ bar: 10, baz: '20', xxx: 0 });
console.log(f.options);
// expected: { bar: '10', baz: 20, xxx: 0 }
// actual { bar: 10, baz: '20', xxx: 0 }
```

Is it possible to make it works? All properties sets via `this.options[key]`, but I expect that `bar` and `buz` should be set via this[key]`.

Comment: Hi, @CertainPerformance. I've updated my question to be more specific.

Comment: See other dupe - `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` doesn't work because the setter is on the *prototype*, not the instantiated object (`this`) itself. Use `const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Foo.prototype, key);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the syntax to do this would be (untested)

```
this[key] = val;
```

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question.